# A tracking tool to help with your Mass Effect 3 missions

Tags: discussion, me3missions

I put this together from bits and pieces of other tools that I've built in the past:

http://withoutthesarcasm.com/stackapps/

Click on "ME3Mission" to load the tool.  You'll be prompted by Stack Exchange for access to some account information.  There's details about what that means and what data the tool has access to on the landing page.

This tool will query the API and give you information about what posts of yours are close to +5 or +8, which are the two thresholds for mission completion during the ME3 promotion.

All the post links are "share" links that you can get referral clicks on.  Sharing a link doesn't guarantee you more upvotes, but it can't hurt :)

There's a limitation of 100 posts per category - after time and score filtering, but before tag filtering - but I think that number is high enough that you shouldn't notice it.

Feel free to report bugs or request features, however, there's a couple things I can't do:

- Can't track clicks on shared links, unless I made you redirect through my site or something.
- I'm not going to track posts above the thresholds, since the existing mission status tool does that already.
- Not tracking posts towards the +1 counts, simply because it's pretty easy to do this already, and the thresholds here are pretty low.

Everything's open source, using Javascript, so you can educate yourself or check my work by inspecting the source in your browser.

Happy promotion hunting!

Comment: +1! One of the best ways to get over the hump is to look at +3 and +4 posts that can be improved!

Comment: yep this is sweet

Comment: Too bad it can't track share links. I wonder if this will be an API feature in the future.

Comment: @Resorath, yeah, I can see the number of views, but I can't tell the sources.  It would be nice to be able to track what you've shared and how many clicks each one has gotten, but that might be asking a bit too much for a 2-week promotion :)

Comment: Why is it +5 and not +6? +6 is the goal I think, so my +5 posts don't show up on your app.

Comment: @Zeno, the rules state "35 posts with a score of 5 or more," so your goal is to get posts to at least +5 for that part of the mission.

Comment: Oh whoops, I'm on mission 3 which requires 6+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This tool has been awesome.  Thanks so much!

Comment: You guys are quite welcome, I'm glad it was useful.